# Did Muhammad(PBUH) recive revalation about donkeys or not ? hadith contradction

Tags: hadith-interpretation, animals

Prophet said nothing has been revealed to him regarding donkeys.

> Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet was asked about donkeys and he
>   replied, "**Nothing has been revealed** to me regarding donkeys except
>   this comprehensive Verse which **includes everything**: "So whoever does
>   good equal to the weight of an atom (or a smallest ant) shall see it;
>   And whoever, does evil equal to the weight of an atom or a smallest
>   ant) shall see it.' **(99.7-8)**
>
> **Sahih Bukhari** [Vol. 6, Book 60, Hadith 487](https://sunnah.com/urn/46420)
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle said, " Horses are kept for one
>   of three purposes; for some people they are a source of reward, for
>   some others they are a means of shelter and for some others they are a
>   source of sins. The one for whom they are a source of reward, is he
>   who keeps a horse for Allah's Cause (i.e. Jihad) tying it with a long
>   tether on a meadow or in a garden with the result that whatever it
>   eats from the area of the meadow or the garden where it is tied will
>   be counted as good deeds for his benefit, and if it should break its
>   rope and jump over one or two hillocks then all its dung and its foot
>   marks will be written as good deeds for him; and if it passes by a
>   river and drinks water from it even though he had no intention of
>   watering it, even then he will get the reward for its drinking. As for
>   the man for whom horses are a source of sins, he is the one who keeps
>   a horse for the sake of pride and pretense and showing enmity for
>   Muslims: such a horse will be a source of sins for him. When Allah's
>   Apostle was asked about donkeys, he replied, "Nothing has been
>   revealed to me about them except this unique, comprehensive Verse:
>   "Then anyone who does an atom's (or a small ant's) weight of good
>   shall see it; And anyone who does an atom's (or a small ant's) weight
>   of evil, shall see it.' **(99.7-8)**
>   **Sahih Bukhari** [Vol. 4, Book 52, Hadith 112](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/76)

But we find hadiths about donkeys which seems like revelations.

> Narrated Abu Huraira: The Prophet said, "When you hear the crowing of
>   cocks, ask for Allah's Blessings for (their crowing indicates that)
>   they have seen an angel. And when you hear the braying of donkeys,
>   seek Refuge with Allah from satan for **(their braying indicates) that
>   they have seen a satan."**
>
> **Sahih Bukhari** [Vol. 4, Book 54, Hadith 522](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/111)

What should we do with this contradiction ?  Do we have to accept both hadiths as true?

Answer (score 2):

These are separate instances regarding different things.

The first *hadith* is speaking about merits of keeping a donkey.  The *hadith* right before the one you posted explains it=

> Horses are kept for one of three purposes...Then Rasolullah was asked
>   regarding donkeys...

Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 60, *Hadith* #486

Make sure you read the *hadiths* before and after it before asking questions.  The way Imam al-Bukhari arranged his collection was by putting the stronger *hadiths* with better chains first.

Comment: i have read the previous hadith and another one. I will add that to the question so it will be more helpful

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong . Your saying the hadith about donkeys seeing satan is not a revelation.

Comment: Both hadiths are Sahih and correct, but they're not related.  The first one is about merits of keeping a donkey, and to that the Prophet replied nothing was revealed about it i.e. merits of keeping a donkey.

Answer (score 0):

there is no contradiction because hadithes are not revealed (original : "yunzal", "unzila" ) by god, but muhammad's own words.

there are some exceptions: hadithes named qudsi, and some about actions of jabrail. but generally they are considered words of muhammad. those you said about are surely not revelation from god. but even those speaches of allah that are in qudsi hadithes may be not pure words of god, but retelled by muhammad and maybe slightly changed. i am not sure, and that is for another question. and actions of jabrail are narrated by muhammad.